# Get address from coordinates with react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

Using react-leaflet, I want to get the location address information from coordinates.

I found a working example of a similar behavior: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/y0znnj58l1?file=/src/Map.js:287-301)

However it seems it doesn't work with my version of react-leaflet. Also I don't even need it to work with onClick events, just get the address on page load so i can populate a form field.

Any push in the right direction would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking after a reverse geocoding service. You can start by looking into [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/) it is free and it is what they use in the example. However remember to read the usage policy, it is not meant for heavy use. If you know that you will make a lot i requests each second you should look for a paid alternative.

Would recommend to build your own service that can take coordinates and pass that to the api, relaying on a package. e.g.

I have a graphql query hook that I pass latLng that I get from leaflet -> pass it through my backend -> Nominatim.

```
const { data, fetching, error } = useReverseGeo(latLng);
```